# Deploy user.config file

Tags: c#, deployment, user.config

I'm having problems deploying a config file.

I have a set of default configurations, which are altered at the moment of installation (custom installer class).

But strangely, my settings keep being reset. In VS2005 *all* settings are defined with default value, but it's just not getting into my deploy software.

What can i do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you are somehow altering the wrong user.config file?

Each new version of your application gets a new folder under the folder below (Windows 7):

C:\Users>username>\AppData\Local\\App.exe_Url_fdtzgjq\

Each subfolder contains a separate user.config:

- \0.5.0.0\user.config
- \0.9.0.0\user.config
- \1.0.0.0\user.config

etc.